# Grails compiles but Groovy fails

Tags: grails, groovy

I tested the following code in the Groovy Console and both fails as expected:
The first test:

```
class TekEvent {
  Date organizer 
}

  def tekEvent = new TekEvent(organizer: 'John Doe')
  assert tekEvent.organizer == 'John Doe'

  Exception thrown
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'John Doe' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'
```

The second test:

```
class DifferentTekEvent {
  String name 
 }

 def tekEvent = new TekEvent(nameNot: 'John Doe')
 assert tekEvent.nameNot == 'John Doe'
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: nameNot for class: DifferentTekEvent
```

The equivalents are run in Grails (i.e. the classes are instantiated and used in the unit tests) but the exceptions are not thrown. for example:

```
@TestFor(TekEvent)
class TekEventSpec extends Specification {

void "test"() {

    def tekEvent = new TekEvent(organizer: 'aasdf') //no expceptions thrown here. Why?
    expect:
        tekEvent.organizer == 'aasdf'
}
}
```

May I know why is there is discrepancy? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Grails, the [Data binding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#dataBinding) takes effect when you construct a domain class.

So no exceptions are thrown, but if you see the `errors` property on the domain instance, you will see some messages there.

afaik, if the domain class doesn't have a property defined (like 'nameNot') in your example, it will simply ignore that.

Comment: Right, this is to support stuff like `new User(params)` in controllers, where the `params` map will contain properties like controller and action which can't be bound to the domain class.